# Javascript works in dev but not prod. Looking for advice

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

all my js and css work in dev but not prod.  I've been on this problem for 2 weeks.  Please advise.  Specifically type ahead drop downs are not working.  I've tried a lot of reordering and such already, but let me know if you see something.  I've tried precompiling and not precompiling.  I've tried changing the values of the configuration file.

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

production.rb:

```
myApp::Application.configure do

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  #default false ^^
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  #defualt false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true
  #defualt true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
  #default = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery_ujs.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( twitter/bootstrap.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap-typeahead.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( rails.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( autocomplete-rails.js )


  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

app/assets/application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/modules/canvas-tools
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
//= require bootstrap-typeahead
//= require rails
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function()     {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
} );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popover-myasset').popover();
});
```

Comment: I am also experiencing this very annoying issue.

Comment: You should put all of the js you want to run on document.ready inside one document.ready event handler. Not sure what's up with your other issue though.

Comment: Have you checked out the Net tab in your browser's inspector to make sure the static resources are being loaded properly in production?

Comment: 1. remove everything from "config.assets.precompile. 2. post back the errors that you're getting in your javascript console log

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to check if static resources are being properly loaded.  The network profile shows application.css with /assets under it.  Same with application.js.  Hmmm, I guess /public should be under it?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, all I get there is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" .... application.js, which points to this line: "extend(CanVGRenderer.prototype, SVGRenderer.prototype);"

Comment: Sounds like a highcharts problem -- can you remove those requires for now to verify that this will work once there aren't anymore javascript errors on the page?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: OK, keep removing until something works. That's the core issue here, you have a javascript error, so the rest of your javascript isn't going to execute.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, if I get rid of jquery_ujs and highcharts/modules/canvas-tools I can use the dropdowns.  But then my charts don't show up.  I tried keeping that and reordering it with the autocomplete-rails with no luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep -- your charts are broken

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, just to understand... you are suggesting there is an error in the highcharts/modules/canvas-tools.js file?  It blows my mind that it works in dev then.

Comment: It's more likely that the data is different in production and is failing because ofthat

Comment: @JesseWolgamott, do you mean the database data?  I'm testing the prod release on the same db as dev.

Comment: ok, last suggestion, change to false: `config.assets.compress = true`... if that's not it, you should remove and re-add this question focusing on the highcharts and not on the subsequent twitter bootstrap problem.