# Rails production: javascript not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

Recently I've got strange error on Rails production - some javascripts not working. Locally there is no problem - everything works perfectly, but production.

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery.minicolors
//= require widget
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/highstock
//= require_tree .
```

scripts that not working - `jquery.minicolors` and `widget`(coffescript).

I've tried to add these scripts to

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( widget.js.coffee jquery.minicolors.js )
```

in `production.rb`, but that's doesn't work too

It's strange but if I remove

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/highstock
```

from `application.js` the rest scripts work fine

Comment: Did you acutally precompile the assets?

Comment: Anything in console?

Comment: @japed check out update I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution with help of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110496/javascript-works-in-dev-but-not-prod-looking-for-advice?rq=1)

I removed from `application.js`

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

and keep only

```
//= require highcharts/highstock
```

`highstock.js` keeps in `/vendor/assets/javascripts` and contains necessary scripts for highcharts working

Answer (score 1):

I understand this issue has been closed but I actually had the same issue recently. I fixed it by wrapping my jQuery code inside the following;

```
    $(document).ready(

     (custom JS goes here)

)
```

If you (or anyone in the future) has the same issue, I'd say it's cause of how Rails loads CSS/HTML and jQuery. Apparently jQuery is loaded as the head in a Rails app so it's loaded but can't be accessed after it's been loaded.